Find eccentricity of orbit given the velocity and the semi-major axis
Is it possible to calculate eccentricity of orbit knowing only the semi-major axis and the velocity of both celestial bodies? If not, what other additional information is required.
Does the fact that the satellite is launched tangentially with earth make any difference. I don't think it does because we assume the earth is a sphere, but I figured it may have a nuance which I am not familiar with. Thank you.

v = sqrt((GM/a)(1 + e)/(1 - e)), where a is the semi-major axis. Wolfram Alpha can solve for e using those parameters.

We'll get a negative e for the earth round the sun in that case

Sid N -- sqrt((G * M / a) * (1 - e) / (1 + e)) is for aphelion speed. sqrt((G * M / a) * (1 + e) / (1 - e)) is for perihelion speed. If you're getting negative numbers, then you are doing something wronig.

Relating Average Velocity to Orbital Period:
$$T^2 = \frac{4 \pi^2 a^3}{G M}$$
$$v = \frac{2 \pi a}{T}$$
Combining the Equations:
$$v = \frac{2 \pi a}{\sqrt{\frac{4 \pi^2 a^3}{G M}}} = \frac{2 \pi a}{2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{G M}}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{G M}}} = \sqrt{\frac{G M}{a}}$$
Considering the Average Velocity:
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{G M}{a}} \left(1 - \frac{e^2}{2}\right)$$
$$e^2 = 2 \left(1 - \frac{v}{\sqrt{\frac{G M}{a}}}\right)$$
$$e = \sqrt{2 \left(1 - \frac{v}{\sqrt{\frac{G M}{a}}}\right)}$$
(Valid for very large object mass difference, like the earth or sun, but can't be used for binary star systems, etc. Taking barycentre is a must in such cases)
